# Masking a centred image relative to its parent

Tags: html, css

I have two parts to my background: a repeated pattern, and a fixed image in the center – done like so:

```
body {
    background: url('http://www.bathroomsandkitchenstoo.com/BK/home_files/Tile_background2.jpg');
}
#center {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent url('http://www.cadenhead.org/workbench/gems/floating-head-of-canterbury.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
​
<body>
    <div id="center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div><!-- page content, br's here as example to show how #center is "fixed" --><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
</body>
```

See [jsfiddle.net/Ps9JV](http://jsfiddle.net/Ps9JV/).

[image]

What I'm trying to do is keep the fixed image central, but mask it to a 300px x 300px square in the top left of the body, like below. Is there any cross browser way to do this without javascript?

[image]

Comment: Really odd requirement: i don't think you can do it with CSS only (but i'm not sure). Fixed positioning isn't intended to be "dynamic", you should know top and left margins in pixels at least...

Comment: @AndreaLigios It's possible with CSS, see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229743/how-to-have-width-kpx-50-without-using-calc , but I can't work out how to do it without calc

Comment: Of course, and as you can see, that example has top and left margins set in pixels :) I don't think you can do it in a fully dynamic way, even with calc()...

Comment: @AndreaLigios No it doesn't? The image size can be hardcoded, the 300px x 300px can be hardcoded, it's the body size that can't be, and it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with `calc`, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vVCFF/)

```
body {
    background: url('http://www.bathroomsandkitchenstoo.com/BK/home_files/Tile_background2.jpg');
}
#c {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 50%;
}
#center {
    /* image is 450px x 300px */
    width: -moz-calc(525px - 50%);
    width: -webkit-calc(525px - 50%);
    width: -o-calc(525px - 50%);
    width: calc(525px - 50%);
    height: -moz-calc(450px - 50%);
    height: -webkit-calc(450px - 50%);
    height: -o-calc(450px - 50%);
    height: calc(450px - 50%);
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -225px;
    background: transparent url('http://www.cadenhead.org/workbench/gems/floating-head-of-canterbury.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```